# como lanzar una instancia spot en aws?

Tags: servidor, aws, cloud, amazon

Holas amigos , ante todo gracias de antemano mi duda es la siguiente , estoy probando aws y tengo una aplicacion en una instancia ec2 on-demand , mi pregunta es si puedo volver esa instancia una instancia ec2 spot , y si no que me expliquen como crear un instancia spot desde 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No es posible convertir una instancia que ya esté corriendo en una Spot, si deseas pasarla a este esquema deberás sacar una imagen de esta y lanzarla nuevamente desde la consola "Spot Instances" o usando el AWS CLI especificando el identificador de la AMI generado.

Comment: Muchas Gracias compañero